# How to add unique constraint on combination of two fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to add unique constraint on combination of two fields **design-time** in ClientDataSet.

[image]

This works but it changes index in ascending order(by default) and mess my code,

I think, i want to add the constraint from here

[image]

but it's obviously wrong way to do it and i cant find any information on google for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what's on the first picture but specify semicolon separated field list in the [**DescFields**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TIndexDef.DescFields) property as well. That defines the fields of the index that will be sorted in descending order.

Comment: My bad for not adding this to the question, but i don't want any order to be changed.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand. What's on the picture creates an ascending unique index (_"but it changes index in ascending order"_). Specifying `DescFields` makes it descending. So what exactly do you want to create?

Comment: I want to create unique constraint on combination of two fields, without changing any Indices.

Comment: Let me clarify. What's in the `Constraints` collection are so called check constraints and are used to throw an error when an expression doesn't apply to the record (e.g. field value is not in value range). What's in the `IndexDefs` are indices, but it includes indices that are unique. That means, you can specify primary index as well as unique index that can be in descending order.

Comment: Look behind this simple situation stays relatively complex synchronization between two grids and changing order of one of them mess the whole picture. I just want to prevent user for adding same parameter again with this unique constraint but i guess i will have to do it manually.

Comment: Those unique indices can be not only for ensuring unique values in listed columns, but they can be also ordered (which can improve e.g. sorting of datasets if it matches the given index field order). If you need to just prevent inserting duplicate values, creating unique index with no specified ordering is enough. It doesn't affect sorting of a dataset though. That's what `IndexName` property does. There you must pick the index by which you want to sort.

Comment: I would expand my answer but don't know your problem (maybe I see your aim, you want to prevent inserting same field values and keep sorting of the dataset by different fields than the unique ones). So maybe you've created two indices - a primary key and the unique key one and all that happened is that the `IndexName` property has changed and your dataset started to be sorted by that unique key index. I don't know.